# What's the difference between AOC's Green New Deal and Sanders' Green New Deal?

Tags: united-states, climate-change, environmental-policy, green-new-deal

Both [Congresswoman Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_New_Deal) and [Senator Bernie Sanders](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/22/climate/bernie-sanders-climate-change.html) have revealed a sweeping plan to inact environmental policies that would, among other things, attempt to slow the progress of climate change and depletion of natural resources. Each has informally titled their plan the "Green New Deal."

**What are the differences between these two plans,** with regards to the issues addressed and the specific solutions addressing them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental difference between these plans....is that one is a plan and the other is simply a statement to make a plan.

[This answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/43873/19306) from a question I asked recently addresses why the Alexandria Ocasio Cortez's resolution that you cite does not contain details:

> > Recognizing the duty of the Federal Government **to create** a Green New
> >     Deal.
>
> The thing you called “the Green New Deal” isn’t actually the Green New
>   Deal, it’s a statement that the government should create a Green New
>   Deal sometime in the future, along with a very broad description of
>   what that should look like.

So Rep. Ocasio-Cortez's resolution is not a plan, just a call to make a plan. However, [Senator Sanders's Plan](https://berniesanders.com/issues/the-green-new-deal/) is his detailed proposal that is his way of enacting this call to make a plan:

> As president, Bernie Sanders will launch the decade of the Green New Deal, a ten-year, nationwide mobilization centered around justice and equity during which climate change will be factored into virtually every area of policy, from immigration to trade to foreign policy and beyond.

As to your specific question, these texts largely address the same issues, but Senator Sanders' plan contains specific solutions, whereas Rep. Ocasio-Cortez's  resolution contains overarching goals.