# Green New Deal. Does it implies realization in the US only?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, climate-change, ecology, green-new-deal

You may hear about that new democratic program - [Green New Deal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_New_Deal)
It sounds very interesting, as it is huge, and gives bonuses for nearly all.

But this program implies huge changes in the US. In some point of time, US can become weaker than now, or even vulnerable - imagine that you are doing a big repair/reconstruction in you house. There would be time, when you should replace your iron fences and gates with modern fences and gates from something ecological. Would you be vulnerable without fences? I'm sure you would.

But you surely be safe, if all others would do the same in their houses (if all other countries also imply GND) - when all are working, there is no time for conflicts.

Does this program implies analogical changes in all other countries? Or sort of pressure towards those, who do not want to?

Comment: Climate change mitigation does present the "tragedy of commons" problem, namely that a single (large) country can subvert the effort. https://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=120883813

Comment: @Fizz, is it a start of an answer? And I do not understand, why are you downvoting. Somewhere here is a question about countries, accepting bonuses from global warming. Does GND implies some actions towards such countries?

Comment: I didn't downvote. And this is too short for an answer. It is a (terminology) pointer for you to look at.

Comment: @Fizz, really sorry, timing of these events - your comment and someones, downvote is tricking me.

Answer (score 9):

It should probably be noted that the Green New Deal isn't a full set of policies. It's a policy to make a policy. This is discussed in another question on the site, regarding the differences between Sanders' and AOC's [policies](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43918/whats-the-difference-between-aocs-green-new-deal-and-sanders-green-new-deal).

The question implies that the current state of construction specifically and the economy in general can only be hindered by implementation of green policies that would combat climate change at the cost of economic progress and safety standards.

This is a false dichotomy that should be challenged. The Green economy is a growth [industry](http://www.lse.ac.uk/GranthamInstitute/news/how-many-green-jobs-in-the-us/).

> During 2016, the US solar workforce increased by 25% and the number of employees in the US wind energy industry increased by 32 %.

There are enormous opportunities in [exporting renewable energy](http://innodigest.com/exporting-renewable-energy-technologies/) technologies to developing countries that will both cut global greenhouse emissions and potentially earn huge profits for innovators.

> Unlike the majority of developed countries, some developing countries are experiencing now unprecedented levels of economic growth. The largest fast-growing countries, such as Brazil, China and India, will cover most of this growth. As the result, they will be responsible for most of the future energy consumption and greenhouse gas emissions. The development, transfer and use of renewable energy technologies are promising ways towards energy security and low-carbon economy in these countries.

In the [construction](https://www.pbctoday.co.uk/news/energy-news/green-technology-construction/52492/) industry specifically, Green technology is more about sustainability of the structure than any specific materials used.

> The health and safety of the building occupants are fundamental and must be guaranteed during the construction of any building or home. As such, sustainable indoor technologies are mandatory for green construction. The materials used have to ensure green safety standards which include hazardous free elements, non-toxic materials, low volatile emissions, and moisture resistance

All these articles are ones I've turned up in the last five minutes. They should not be considered as the best possible statements of position, they merely indicate that the is no reason to think transition to a green economy is damaging or will cause economic collapse.

A key part of such standards is ensuring that imports meet the same levels of sustainability. It does little good to move from coal to renewable energy sources, if all your imported steel is made in countries that have not made a similar transition. The US [both imports](https://www.trade.gov/steel/countries/pdfs/imports-us.pdf) and exports steel for example. International agreements such as the [Paris accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Agreement) are fundamental in getting the whole world to transition. But even without international agreement technology innovators will prosper over those that refuse to change as has been the case with every new technology since the industrial revolution.

Comment: you touch question in the last paragraph.) What if there would be no states  with the same level of sustainability? And fences I mention, was about military in most. Military consumes a lot of oil, obviously. What to do with it? Would be great, if you add something about it to you, enormous at least, answer.) Thank you.

Comment: The US military is obscenely large. The two war doctrine has been considered for removal since 2010. If it goes, so does a massive amount of that consumption. No part of moving to a green deal requires compromise on safety or security. It just requires thinking a bit harder about how you provide them.

Comment: thank for your reply. So, US would reduce its armed forces heavily - I understand it. But, continuing, for me, it is very disputable, if China (which isn't in climate treaties, as I remember), replace all its factories and plants with new, ecological,  which it'll buy in US. For what?

Comment: Ah, I see your edit - just because new technologies are better. It is disputable, of course. If it would be so, there would be no such dotations for it in EU, for example - because when business see profits, it'll use it without club over it, wouldn't it? But in fact, it is a good answer, thank you.

Comment: I mean, if it is so profitable and good, why each and every country not ruining its oil production and non-ecological power plants? Like after oil-consuming engines were invented, or airplanes. I'm exaggerating, but the point is the same.

Comment: These are new technologies. They're growing and improving, but huge barriers exist in the form of the economic and political clout of the industries they are trying to replace. This IMF report places US fossil fuel [subsidies](https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WP/Issues/2019/05/02/Global-Fossil-Fuel-Subsidies-Remain-Large-An-Update-Based-on-Country-Level-Estimates-46509) in one year at [$649m](https://www.rollingstone.com/politics/politics-news/fossil-fuel-subsidies-pentagon-spending-imf-report-833035/) That's a big hurdle to get over.

Comment: Understand about barriers, thank you. And, probably, I understand your cornerstone. As these new technologies are(or supposed to be) the best, GND is aiming to make a "big jump" towards those new technologies. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Yes. I think you've understood my point.

Answer (score 1):

### Never forget the nukes

Per wikipedia:

> As of 2019, the U.S. has an inventory of 6,185 nuclear warheads; of these, 2,385 are retired and awaiting dismantlement and 3,800 are part of the U.S. stockpile. Of the stockpiled warheads, the U.S. stated in its March 2019 New START declaration that 1,365 are deployed on 656 ICBMs, SLBMs, and strategic bombers

Each warhead is capable of obliterating a large city, power plant, oil refinery, military base, port, etc. Towards the end of the Cold War the estimated casualties produced by using the whole arsenal on the Soviet Union would have been in the hundreds of millions of people.

*That* is the real guarantor of security for the US. Everything else is just to facilitate smaller, less drastic, overseas wars. Many of these are of questionable benefit to the US in the first place. It would have been far better to have spent the trillion dollars of the Iraq war on domestic benefits, for example.

### Global war on climate change

While the GND itself doesn't cause other countries to do anything, there are a set of global agreements on carbon reduction. Such as the [Paris Accords.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Agreement) Although the US has announced its withdrawal for those.

### Decarbonisation of the military

Post-20th century war is mostly logistics. Far more personnel are devoted to moving things around than actually fighting. The actual fighting is dependent on tons of fuel for vehicles and aircraft. An example of this is that in the Afghanistan war, every single drop of fuel used had to be shipped overland by tanker truck from Pakistan. It's 1500km from Karachi to Kabul. This supply line was extremely vulnerable to attack by terrorists: fuel trucks burn nicely.

Oil refineries also burn nicely. [A drone strike took out 5% of global production.](https://www.theguardian.com/business/live/2019/sep/16/oil-price-saudi-arabia-iran-drone-markets-ftse-pound-brexit-business-live) This problem is likely to get worse as drone technology gets cheaper and the situation in the Middle East deteriorates. The military need an energy supply that still works even if every well from Riyadh to Tehran is on fire.

The military have noticed this and have their own plans to reduce their usage of oil and replace it with local renewables or portable nuclear reactors. [The US Navy have a jet fuel from seawater programme](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn17632-how-to-turn-seawater-into-jet-fuel/).

Energy security through renewables is also national security through independence on imported fuel. This is even more true for non-US NATO countries that don't have lots of their own oil production.

Answer (score 0):

As the US government cannot dictate policy for the rest of the world, it's quite obvious it would cover the US only.

Of course the "deal" if adopted may well make it impossible for other countries to have economic and political ties with the USA unless they themselves adopt the same policies, but that'd still leave a lot of countries who will decide they'd rather survive than submit to the lunacy a lot of the GND requires (whether the heart of those drafting it is in the right place or not, its implementation even in part would of necessity utterly ruin the economy and reform society into a fully state controlled system without many of the individual freedoms people know and love).

For example if the "deal" requires all companies doing business with the USA to prove they have a complete "zero carbon" production and shipping process, that'd make it impossible for pretty much everyone to export goods to the USA as any such export using any means at all except horse drawn carts would be excluded. And that doesn't even take into consideration the manufacturing process and procurement of raw materials.

Yet that's pretty much the only thing the US could do to get other countries to comply, tell them that the USA will cut diplomatic and economic ties with them unless they adopt the same thing themselves.

While some countries may do this, especially some European countries that are already considering similar proposals, many more will decide that they'd rather trade with Russia and China.

Comment: Why downvoting? It is logical answer, I think, isn't it?

Comment: "For example if the "deal" requires all companies doing business with the USA to prove they have a complete "zero carbon" production and shipping process," Is this part of the proposals? Or is this fanciful scaremongering?

Comment: You talk about it yourself in comments, didn't you? About steel consumption - from only the same level of sustainability?

Comment: @Jontia it's an example of how they could push other countries to adopt it. And I'd fully expect it to be part of the requirement for all US companies, at least in the more radical variants.

Comment: Why would you expect that? A quote or a link to substantiate it would be helpful. It's a really specific idea that you've provided, and GND isn't even a concrete set of policies itself yet. So if you're going to use concrete policies to say why GND is bad, then backing up those points with evidence is necessary.

Comment: I take issue with the horse drawn carts as a GND compliant trasit solution...  As the GND does have language about reducing greenhouse gasses created by, um, livestock flatulence.   Though they use less technical jargon than I did in the bill.

Comment: You seem to make a lot of specific policy claims about a concept that has no specific policies outlined. The deal is essentially an agreement to strive to reach non-compromise goals by acknowledging the necessity of massive, fundamental change, and gives some very, very broad brushstrokes to some of what that might mean. Anyone claiming that specific policies from the New Green Deal would mean X or Y is working from misinformation, since there are no specific policy initiatives yet.